# Parser de data em C

Tags: c, string, data, parser

Estava fazendo uns testes para fazer *parsers* de data e fiz este exemplo baseado em um programa que formata através do `sscanf()` com uma *string* constante definida porem não entendi bem onde está o erro:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int day, year;
   char weekday[20], month[20], dtm[100];

   printf
    (
     "\n\tDigite Dia Mes a ano em string"
     "\n\tex.(Saturday March 25 1989): "
    );

   scanf("%s80[^\n]",&dtm);

   sscanf(dtm, "%s %s %d  %d", &weekday, &month, &day, &year);

   printf("%s %d, %d = %s\n", month, day, year, weekday);

   return 0;
} 

/*
 Input: 
   Saturday March 25 1989

 Output:

  `l 0, 0 = Saturday
```

onde o Output deveria ser:

March 25 1989 Saturday
    */

Comment: Isso é uma pergunta ou uma resposta?

Comment: é uma pergunta queria entender qual o erro é que eu esqueci de descrever tentando formatar o codigo aqui mas nao consegui ai alguem formatou ele..

Comment: na verdade o output ai deveria ser:  March 25 1989  Saturday

Comment: Edite sua pergunta para ficar claro para todo mundo, isso deve atrair mais pessoas para responder.

Comment: Esse código nem compila. Pelo menos em um bom compilador.

Comment: C ou C++? Creio que você cometeu um ligeiro engano ao marcar a linguagem

Comment: @dark777 A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: a resposta que me ajudou ja foi votada...

Answer (score 1):

Isto não é exatamente um *parse* de data, é de uma *string* com 4 separações entre espaços que em tese os 2 últimos devem ser números, nada mais que isto.

Na verdade o erro está na entrada de dados. O padrão do [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) está errado.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int day, year;
    char weekday[20], month[20], dtm[100];
    printf(
        "\n\tDigite Dia Mes a ano em string"
        "\n\tex.(Saturday March 25 1989): "
    );
    scanf("%[^\n]s80", dtm);
    printf("%s\n", dtm);
    sscanf(dtm, "%s %s %d  %d", weekday, month, &day, &year);
    printf("%s %d, %d = %s\n", month, day, year, weekday);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/daIf4M), e no [**repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ziycspjb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/ParseDate.c).

Comment: agora sim deu certo... funfou legal na verdade eu me inspirei mais a procurar sobre isso baseado em um programa que tenho em linguagem D. como exemplo:  import std.format;

void main() {
    string s = "Name Surname 18";
    string name, surname;
    int age;
    formattedRead(s, "%s %s %s", &name, &surname, &age);
    // %s selects a format based on the corresponding argument's type
}

Comment: Ué, você removeu o `scanf()` inteiramente? Como é que os dados vão chegar na `dtm`?

Comment: @Wtrmute eu copiei o código errado :)